# Only one class value changing

Tags: javascript, html

I currently use a textfield to change text inside my html.

My textfield:

```
  Voornaam:
  <h3 class="title1">Kevin</h3>
  <input type="text" id="myTextField1" />
  <br/><br/>
```

When done typing text, press the button:

```
  <input type="button" id="myBtn" value="Change" />
```

Which triggers this function:

```
document.querySelector('#myBtn').addEventListener('click', function change() {
  function isInvalid(input) {
    return input.value.length == 0;
  }

  var titles = [...document.querySelectorAll('[class^="title"]')];
  var inputs = [...document.querySelectorAll('[id^="myTextField"]')];
  var anchor = document.querySelector('#myLink');

  if (inputs.some(isInvalid)) {
    alert('Write some real text please.');

    anchor.href = 'convert.php';
  } else {
    var querystring = inputs.map((input, index) => `var${index + 1}=${titles[index].textContent = input.value}`);
//    $('.title'+index).html(input.value);

    anchor.href = `convert.php?${querystring.join('&')}`;
  }
});
```

The value above the textfield:

```
<h3 class="title1">Kevin</h3>
```

does change and this is good, however it requires to be changed somewhere else aswell. And this one does not seem to change.. The other one that should be changed is:

```
  <p class="title1">Test.</p><p class="title2">Achternaam</p>
```

class title one should also be changed here although that does not happen.

Could anybody tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the code you have provided, the mistake you make is that you have an array of 1 input elements: `#myTextField1`

You loop this array of 1 via map to change the the title array (an array of 3 or so from what I can tell). But the thing is, because the input array only has index 0, you will also only change the first element of the titles array.

Now that I completely understand the code, here is a possible fix. You basically want to do the title selector once you know the index of the elements you are searching for.

```
  var inputs = [...document.querySelectorAll('[id^="myTextField"]')];
  var querystring = inputs.map((input) => {
      // Remove all leading non-digits to get the number
      var number = input.id.replace( /^\D+/g, '');

      var titles = [...document.querySelectorAll('.title'+ number)];
      titles.forEach((title) => title.innerHTML = input.value);
      return `var${number}=${input.value}`;
  });
```

Also, instead of depending on the clean luck of the indexes given to you by the querySelectorAll (when element with id *'myTextField1'* is not the first to be found in the DOM, you are screwed), I now take the number from the id string value instead => variable `number`.

Check here for a [working fiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/f2stqv7m/1/).

Comment: Seems understandable, It's for more than 3 titles. Currently there is 7 and perhaps more to come. could you provide and example of how you would loop over the titles array?

Comment: I'm just not sure what you want with these inputs e.g. how many input elements do you expect to be in that array? How will you know which input array entry maps to which title elements.

Comment: Oh ok, myTextField1 should change elements h3:title1 and p:title1. I think I get it.

Comment: Uhm yes, that's it! They should both the changed.

Comment: i see what you're doing and it is really a good idea, however it doesn't seem to work. Also you might've missed the fact where in my code i add var1,var2,var3 etc. after a href link. This should not be removed as it is really necessary for my project. I excuse myself for not pointing this out before.

Comment: Actually, it does work. And also the querystring is returned like in your example. I only edited the code however where the problem resided. So not all that I omitted should be removed. I'm updating my answer with a working fiddle so you can check it out.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146731/discussion-between-kevin-bosman-and-nico-van-belle).